# Spring MongoDB TCP connection ends then does a query

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I am having a very strange problem with Spring 3.1 and MongoDB.  I am using the Spring Mongo libs.   This is a pretty simple call just pulls some data and inserts some new data.  But as it is in the loop when pulling new data the connection is killed.  From a capture I see it pull data insert data, then do another query but after a two second delay it sends a FIN packet to the server.  the server then a little bit later tries to send data back to the client, but after that the client sends RSTs as it has already killed the connection.

Please let me know what other information I can provide to help understand this issue.  I can provide a download link for the a capture file as well.

Thank you for your help

Trace output

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: can't call something : id561la.ytel.com/172.31.214.55:27017/cdrstat; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : id561la.ytel.com/172.31.214.55:27017/cdrstat
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1665)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1548)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:495)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:486)
    at dao.BaseMongoSQLDAO.queryForList(BaseMongoSQLDAO.java:35)
    at dao.PrefixStatSqlMapDAO.list(PrefixStatSqlMapDAO.java:59)
    at services.CDRReaderService.getPrefixStat(CDRReaderService.java:705)
    at services.CDRReaderService.processFile(CDRReaderService.java:659)
    at services.CDRReaderService.access$100(CDRReaderService.java:42)
    at services.CDRReaderService$1.run(CDRReaderService.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : id561la.ytel.com/172.31.214.55:27017/cdrstat
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:295)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:257)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:310)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:295)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:368)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:459)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:484)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1534)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:46)
    at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:33)
    at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:28)
    at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:124)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:74)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:286)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: This error often happens when the network connection fails.  Does this happen to you regularly (i.e. can you provide a test case that reproduces the problem), or was it an isolated incident?  If the latter, can you trace if there were any problems with the network at the time?

Comment: This seems to happen anytime I try to select data out of the system.  I was developing this originally with the DB and the App on the same server. Then when I moved it to a seperate server it started having this problems.  This definitely is not Isolated.  It happens consistently.  I am not sure I am going to be able to provide a test case.  I don't want to sound unhelpful, but I unfortunately need to either see if this was a simple problem to fix or select a different solution.  I appreciate the response.